# How do I manually configure the Link module?

Tags: 8, files, uri

I would like to be able to add the `file://` protocol to the list of `filter_protocols` so that we can add links to shared company files on a mapped drive from within our intranet website, but I'm not sure how to do this. Right now, it is apparently not included, according to [Link Module Overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/link/overview). Is there a way to manually configure this list in order to add `file://`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override that in a container services file.

For example, create/edit /sites/default/services.yml, and add/alter the following lines:

```
parameters:
  filter_protocols:
    - http
    - https
    - ftp
    - news
    - nntp
    - tel
    - telnet
    - mailto
    - irc
    - ssh
    - sftp
    - webcal
    - rtsp
    - file
```

and make sure you have this line uncommented/added to settings.php:

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/services.yml';
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried that and it unfortunately did not work for me. In my `sites/default/` directory i have two files besides my newly created `services.yml` file and the preexisting `settings.php` file: `default.services.yml` and `default.settings.php`. I edited both of these default files in the same way you described above for the non-default `settings.php` and `services.yml`. When I click on my html link on my web-page, `<a href="file://C:/Users/AdamNoack/Desktop/test1.docx">local file</a>` nothing happens. I have tried many different variations of this `a` tag and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is it on a local domain? Some browser security policies disallow embed/redirect to file:// protocol for local domains. If that's the problem it's not one Drupal can help to solve; Drupal's only involvement is rendering the `file:///` URL in the first place

Comment: Oh you're right! It now at least works in IE. Doesn't work in chrome though. Thank you!

Comment: It works in chrome with this chrome extension: [enable local file links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld/related?hl=en-US)

Comment: +1 this is an awesome answer.  For my project I needed to have WhatsApp symbol as a menu link within a standard Drupal menu. [fontawesome_menu_icons](https://drupal.org/project/fontawesome_menu_icons) solved the visual - provided a WhatsApp symbol, along with [menu_link_attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) for styling. 1 / 2

Comment: 2 / 2 But the final piece of the puzzle was getting Drupal menu link editor to accept `whatsapp://` protocol which is part of the sharing link `whatsapp://send?text=https://drupal.stackexchange.com` - by default Drupal doesn't accept it, but with your answer @Clive it does! I added `whatsapp` to the end of the list of protocols in `sites/default/services.yml`- and as you say, made sure that the uncommented reference to this was in place in `sites/default/services.php` Thank you so much!

Comment: I would also add that although the link slash `/` characters are "percentified" / "percentage-encoded", like: `whatsapp://send?text=https%3A//drupal.stackexchange.com` - the link still works perfectly. I visited my project site on my mobile, clicked the link and it launched WhatsApp (with the expected obligatory "do you want to launch an external app" notice beforehand), and when I selected the recipient, I saw the perfectly formed link in the messaging area: `https://drupal.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Errata - I should say it was the colon, `:` that was percentified/percentage-encoding to `3A`, the slashes weren't.  But my original comment is still valid about the percentage-encoding not affecting the link, it all works fine.